# change string into datetime in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, date, datetime

How can I change the following string datetime into datetime in python.Here's my dataframe

```
IN  OUT
2022/6/10 10:20:30.00000000000000000000000000   2022/6/17 13:25:30
2022/6/5 12:48:10.0 2022/6/11 10:15
2022/6/9 08:25:30   2022/6/13 10:25:30
2022-06-08 17:18:37.00000000000000000000    0
0   0
2022-06-08 17:18:37 2022/06/08 19:38
```

[[image of df]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRwwE.png)

I want to delete the row containing 0 value and change string into datetime of format `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`.

Here's is my code....

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime as dt

def string_to_date(my_string):
   if '-' and '.' in my_string:
        data=dt.strftime(dt.strptime(my_string[:26],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        return data
   elif '/' and '.' in my_string:
        data=dt.strftime(dt.strptime(my_string[:26],'%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%f'),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        return data
   elif '/' in my_string:
        data=dt.strftime(dt.strptime(my_string[:26],'%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%f'),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        return data
   elif '-' in my_string:
        data=dt.strftime(dt.strptime(my_string[:26],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        return data
   else:
        data=dt.strftime(dt.strptime(my_string[:26],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        return data
```

if **name**=='**main**':

```
df=pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')

col=df.columns[0:]
df=df.loc[~(df=='0').all(axis=1)]
print(df)
i=0
for n in col:
    df[col[i]]=pd.to_datetime(df[col[i]])
    df[col[i]]=df[col[i]].apply(lambda x:string_to_date(x))
    i+=1
print(df)
```

Comment: could you please post the example data as text instead of an image? that would make it much easier to provide you with a good solution ;-)

Comment: Sure.I've added data as text in my qsn. could you please give me the solution.

Comment: I've added & updated an answer, please have a look if that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Letting pandas infer the format should get you started. You can parse to datetime data type like

```py
df['IN'] = pd.to_datetime(df['IN'], errors='coerce')

df['IN']
0   2022-06-10 10:20:30
1   2022-06-05 12:48:10
2   2022-06-09 08:25:30
3   2022-06-08 17:18:37
4                   NaT
5   2022-06-08 17:18:37
Name: IN, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Note that setting keyword `errors='coerce'` leaves `NaT` (not-a-time) for all elements that pandas considers to be not a datetime, e.g. `"0"`

Now you can drop rows that have NaT, e.g.

```py
df['OUT'] = pd.to_datetime(df['OUT'], errors='coerce')

df
                   IN                 OUT
0 2022-06-10 10:20:30 2022-06-17 13:25:30
1 2022-06-05 12:48:10 2022-06-11 10:15:00
2 2022-06-09 08:25:30 2022-06-13 10:25:30
3 2022-06-08 17:18:37                 NaT
4                 NaT                 NaT
5 2022-06-08 17:18:37 2022-06-08 19:38:00

df = df.dropna(axis=0, how='all')

df
                   IN                 OUT
0 2022-06-10 10:20:30 2022-06-17 13:25:30
1 2022-06-05 12:48:10 2022-06-11 10:15:00
2 2022-06-09 08:25:30 2022-06-13 10:25:30
3 2022-06-08 17:18:37                 NaT
5 2022-06-08 17:18:37 2022-06-08 19:38:00
```

---

docs: [pd.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), [pd.DataFrame.dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html), related: [parsing/formatting directives](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)